# PHP variable to array

Tags: php

i need to convert a PHP `$var` to a array.

i did like this

```
$array = array();
$var=$array;
```

but this way the  dosent give the output as this

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 9 [2] => 7 [3] => 11 [4] => 5 )
```

its gives like
    a normal varible print `154515100`

Comment: i don't see how `Array ( [0] => [1] => 9 [2] => 7 [3] => 11 [4] => 5 )` can be related to `154515100`. show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what the variable is. If it is a string, do:
$array = str_split($var);

Answer (score 3):

What is the variable to begin with?

If it was an object, you could cast it to an array like

```
$var=(array)$var;
```

It sounds like you want to convert from a string or an integer to an array, though. Please provide more details.

Comment: i have a string which is stored in a database and i need to convert it to a array in the frontend

Comment: in this way its set as Array ( [0] => 154515100 )

Comment: Oh, okay. Yep, jbenet's answer is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You should define `$var` as array first